# How to resolve "non-numeric argument to binary operator" in R?

Tags: r

This is my full code:

```
library(tree)
library(ISLR)
attach(Carseats)

High = ifelse(Sales <= 8, "No", "Yes")
Carseats = data.frame(Carseats, High)

Carseats$var15 <- NULL
Carseats$var16 <- NULL

tree.carseats = tree(High~.-Sales, Carseats)
summary(tree.carseats)
```

From the **Carseats** data frame, I just deleted two accidentally-created columns (var15 and var16, which all contained NA for all their rows. In order to reproduce this, you must create two columns var15 and var16, with NA as their inputs on rows, at the last indexes.

```
Carseats$var15 <- NULL
Carseats$var16 <- NULL
```

After which, my code for summary(tree.carseats) outputs the following error message:

```
Error in y - frame$yval[object$where] : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

I am supposed to be getting the following output when I run the summary(tree.carseats):

```
Classification tree: tree(formula = High ∼ . - Sales , data = Carseats ) 
Variables actually used in tree construction:
[1] "ShelveLoc " "Price" "Income" "CompPrice "
Test Classification Error
0.05 0.10 0.15 0.20 0.25
[5] "Population " "Advertising " "Age" "US" Number of terminal nodes: 27
Residual mean deviance: 0.4575 = 170.7 / 373 Misclassification error rate: 0.09 = 36 / 400
```

Also take note I receive the warning message when running tree(High ~ . - Sales, Carseats)

```
1: In tree(High ~ . - Sales, Carseats) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In tree(High ~ . - Sales, Carseats) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

In order to reproduce this, you must create 2 additional columns from the Carseats data. I    have no idea how I accidentally made the 2 unnecessary columns, but I believe how I removed them using the code above is the culprit of the error message. Kindly help, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with deletion of columns.

Instead, you have 2 issues.

1. The created vector `High` is not a part of the original dataframe `Carseats`. You must assign that vector back `Carseats` as a new column.
2. The column `Carseats$High` must be a factor rather than a character vector.

```
library(tree)
library(ISLR)
data(Carseats)
Carseats$High = ifelse(Sales <= 8, "No", "Yes")
Carseats$High = as.factor(Carseats$High)
tree.carseats = tree(High~.-Sales, Carseats)
summary(tree.carseats)
#Regression tree:
#tree(formula = High ~ . - Sales, data = Carseats)
#Variables actually used in tree construction:
#[1] "ShelveLoc"   "Price"       "Income"      "Advertising" "CompPrice"   "Age"        
#Number of terminal nodes:  19 
#Residual mean deviance:  0.08725 = 33.24 / 381 
#Distribution of residuals:
#    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
#-0.93750 -0.06250 -0.02000  0.00000  0.06667  0.98000
```

An alternative approach to converting to factor in a separate line would be to perform the operation in the `ifelse` call:

```
Carseats$High = ifelse(Sales <= 8, as.factor(c("No","Yes"))[1],
                                   as.factor(c("No","Yes"))[2])
```

Comment: Thank you! What would be the best way to resolve this or convert it into character?

Comment: Thank you! It worked. However, I am wondering why High = as.factor(ifelse(Sales <= 8, "No", "Yes")) does not work. When I overwritten the existing High variable with the code above, it successfully converted its datatype, but the error messages still occur.

Answer (score 1):

following code works for me:

```
library(tree)
library(ISLR)
attach(Carseats)
High=ifelse(Sales<=8,"No", "Yes")
High=as.factor(High)
Carseats=data.frame(Carseats,High)
tree.carseats=tree(High~.－Sales,Carseats)
summary(tree.carseats)
```